Azure Maps Layers
I am trying to plot multiple circles on a map and have added an event to each polygon layer. However, the issue is that when I click on an inner circle, it triggers all the alerts, meaning it invokes all the events. In Bing Maps, there was a property called zIndex that allowed us to handle the layers this way, but Azure Maps does not provide a similar feature.
here is the Code
    function getMap() {
        //Initialize a map instance.
        map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
            center: [-90, 35],
            zoom: 3,
            view: 'Auto',
                //Alternatively, use an Azure Maps key. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps. NOTE: The primary key should be used as the key.
                authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                subscriptionKey: ''
            }
        });

        //Wait until the map resources are ready.
        map.events.add('ready', function () {
            var temp=[300000,500000,800000]

            temp.forEach(function(data,index){
                 //Create a data source and add it to the map.
            datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
            map.sources.add(datasource);
            datasource.add(new atlas.data.Feature(new atlas.data.Point([-122.5430235659865,48.947622108796494]),
                {
                    subType: "Circle",
                    radius: data
                }));
        var layer=new atlas.layer.PolygonLayer(datasource, null, {
                fillColor: 'rgba(0, 200, 0.8)'
            });
            map.layers.add(layer);

            map.events.add("click", layer,function(){
                alert("Layer"+""+index)
            });

            })
        });

    }


</script>
<style>
    #myMap {
        position: relative;
        width: calc(100% - 210px);
        min-width: 290px;
        height: 600px;
        float: left;
    }

    #output {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 600px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>

<div id="output"></div>

I want to Add z Index To Layer Or Handle It in Way that It Will Not OverLap there Events on One Another

Azure Maps uses a layer base event solution rather than an individual object solution. This is a lot more efficient. Bing Maps actually had this same concept if you used layers in Bing Maps V7.
Azure Maps goes one step further and seperates the data into a data source which allows you to use multiple rendering layers on the same data. (e.g. you could use a polygon layer to render its area one way, a line layer to customize its outline, and a symbol or bubble layer to display it's coordinates). If you want to change the data that is displayed, simply add/remove/edit the data in the data source. Note that GeoJson features are wrapped with the atlas.Shape class when added to a DataSource. If you use the setter functions on the shape class to edit it, the updates automatically flow into the data source and the map is updated.
A couple of key things to note;

Most apps will only need a single data source. Definitely don't create one per shape in a loop. At around 100 data sources the map becomes really slow.
Similarly, you should only create your layers once, not a layer per shape in a loop. If you want to customize how each shape is rendered (e.g. different color), leverage data driven styling. You would also only add the event to the layer once.

I highly recommend watching the video in this doc that explains all of the above: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/data-driven-style-expressions-web-sdk
In the click event callback, the event argument will have a shapes property that has an array of all shapes that are under the mouse and are in the layer the event was added to. Multiple shapes could be returned if there are multiple shapes overtop each other. The top most shape on the map would be the first shape in the array.
Here is an updated version of your code the is more efficient.
var map, dataSource;

function getMap() {
    //Initialize a map instance.
    map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
        center: [-90, 35],
        zoom: 3,
        view: 'Auto',
            //Alternatively, use an Azure Maps key. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps. NOTE: The primary key should be used as the key.
            authType: 'subscriptionKey',
            subscriptionKey: ''
        }
    });

    //Wait until the map resources are ready.
    map.events.add('ready', function () {
        
        //Create a data source and add it to the map.
        datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
        map.sources.add(datasource);

        //Create a layer and add it to the map.
        var layer = new atlas.layer.PolygonLayer(datasource, null, {
            fillColor: 'rgba(0, 200, 0.8)'
        });
        map.layers.add(layer);

        //Add a click event to the layer.
        map.events.add("click", layer,function(e){
            var shape = e.shapes[0];
            var properties = shape.getProperties();
            
            alert("Layer ID: "+ e.layerId + "\nTop most shape radius: " + properties[radius]);
        });
        
        //Loop through and create three circles, add them to the data source.
        var temp=[300000,500000,800000];
        
        temp.forEach(function(data, index){          
            datasource.add(new atlas.data.Feature(new atlas.data.Point([-122.5430235659865,48.947622108796494]), {
                subType: "Circle",
                radius: data
            }));
        });
    });
}

